# IF statements made redundant by ELSE statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm having a go at my first draft of a game (the point of this draft is function over complexity of code so please don't go into how I can condense the code or make it more efficient, that'll come later) and part of that is having characters in each location of the game but I want this to be random. I've added a fair few IF statements to my location function so it tells you which character is in the room and then assigns that character to a variable I've called the Identifier so the game lets you talk to that character. However if there is nobody in the location then there's nobody to talk to so it needs an ELSE statement at the end but if I add an ELSE statement, for some reason I can't work out or find, it makes all of the IF statements totally redundant and makes it so that no matter what, it will always say there's nobody to talk to. If I remove this ELSE statement then the game will crash if you try and talk in a location where there are no characters. How do I fix this??
Many thanks in advance

Comment: have you learnt about arrays?

Comment: Set `identifier` to `None` at the beginning. If it's still `None` at the end, there is nobody in the atrium.

Comment: The `else` applies only to the last `if`. If you want to chain every `if` statement, you need an `if..elif..elif.....else` chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`else` clause only applies to the last `if` and is executed when the `if` condition not met

```
if body == "Atrium":
    print("Brad's dead body lies in the middle of the floor")
    identifier = ei
else:
    identifier = ei
```

In this snippet, `else` gets executed when `body != "Atrium"` - indeed, ingoring all your previous `if` clauses.

**Solution:** [`elif`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html)

```
if murderer.location == "Atrium":
    print(murderer.name, "is stood in here, waiting")
    identifier = murderer
elif innocent1.location == "Atrium":
    print(innocent1.name, "is stood in here, waiting")
    identifier = innocent1
...
else:
    identifier = ei
```

Another alternative is to set `identifier` to the *default value first*, only overwriting it in `if` clauses when the conditions are met. This only works as long as you're not using `identifier` value in the comparisons, of course.

```
identifier = ei
if murderer.location == "Atrium":
...
```

Also, as [@Mitch Wheat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat) mentioned, you should really read about [lists and arrays](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). It's so much easier and cleaner to examine all lists members (especially if you need to add another innocent person later)

```
for innocent in innocents:
    if innocent.location == 'Atrium':
        print(innocent.name, "is stood in here, waiting")
        identifier = innocent
```